# Work with associative arrays INDEXED BY VARCHAR2 based on different record types where not all elements may not be present

Tags: oracle, associative-array, generic-collections

I am trying to work with with parsed data and place into structures to work with.

I have found a Steve Feuersteins package that takes a string, and given seperator(s) will split it out into associative arrays and nested associative arrays.

With some tweaking I have fit it to some additional things I need.  It is initally setup to index the AAs by PLS_INTEGER.  In my case the values that I will be parsing will have identifiers for a given field and I thought it would be good to INDEX BY VARCHAR2 and use the field identifers.  The downfall I see of indexing VARCHAR2 is that if I reference a index that does not exist, I get a NO_DATA_FOUND exception which I don't want.

The setup of the text string by SEPARATORS is:

GROUP/SEGMENT/FIELD/FIELD/FIELD/SEGMENT/FIELD/FIELD/FIELD/SEGMENT/FIELD/GROUP

So for a given segment there are a definitive potential fields but all may not be present so I cannot guarantee that all indexes that I would potentially try to access would be there.

So the current structure of the collection is:

```
SUBTYPE maxvarchar2_t IS VARCHAR2 (4000);

TYPE items_tt IS TABLE OF maxvarchar2_t 
                   INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; 

TYPE nested_items_tt IS TABLE OF items_tt 
                          INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; 

TYPE second_nested_items_tt IS TABLE OF nested_items_tt 
                          INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

So in the example above

I would declare a second_nested_items_tt and it would be assigned:

1 to many GROUPs
  each GROUP would have 1 to many SEGMENTs
  each segment would have 1 to many FIELDs

Here is an example:

```
DECLARE
    group_seperator     CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (1) := CHR (29);
    segment_seperator   CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (1) := CHR (30);
    field_seperator     CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (1) := CHR (28);
    loc_string               VARCHAR2(4000);
--    field_id         VARCHAR2(2);
    idx         VARCHAR2(2);
    TYPE field_id_value_type  IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(2);
    SUBTYPE maxvarchar2_t IS VARCHAR2 (4000);
    fields  field_id_value_type;
    TYPE items_tt IS TABLE OF maxvarchar2_t 
                       INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; 

    TYPE nested_items_tt IS TABLE OF items_tt 
                              INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; 

    TYPE second_nested_items_tt IS TABLE OF nested_items_tt 
                              INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

    dataset  second_nested_items_tt;

    FUNCTION string_to_list (fields_in IN items_tt) --string_in IN VARCHAR2, delim_in IN VARCHAR2) 
      RETURN field_id_value_type

    IS
        fields_out_tbl field_id_value_type;
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN fields_in.FIRST .. fields_in.LAST LOOP
            fields_out_tbl(substr(fields_in(i),1,2)) := SUBSTR(fields_in(i),3,LENGTH(fields_in(i)));        
        END LOOP;

        RETURN fields_out_tbl;
    END string_to_list;

   FUNCTION string_to_list (string_in IN VARCHAR2, delim_in IN VARCHAR2) 
      RETURN items_tt 
   IS 
      c_end_of_list   CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := -99; 
      l_item          maxvarchar2_t; 
      l_startloc      PLS_INTEGER := 1; 
      items_out       items_tt; 

      PROCEDURE add_item (item_in IN VARCHAR2) 
      IS 
      BEGIN 
         IF item_in = delim_in 
         THEN 
            /* We don't put delimiters into the collection. */ 
            NULL; 
         ELSE 
            items_out (items_out.COUNT + 1) := item_in; 
         END IF; 
      END; 

      PROCEDURE get_next_item (string_in         IN     VARCHAR2 
                             , start_location_io IN OUT PLS_INTEGER 
                             , item_out             OUT VARCHAR2 
                              ) 
      IS 
         l_loc   PLS_INTEGER; 
      BEGIN 

         l_loc := INSTR (string_in, delim_in, start_location_io); 

         IF l_loc = start_location_io 
         THEN 
            /* A null item (two consecutive delimiters) */ 
            item_out := NULL; 
         ELSIF l_loc = 0 
         THEN 
         /* We are at the last item in the list. */ 
            item_out := SUBSTR (string_in, start_location_io); 
         ELSE 
            /* Extract the element between the two positions. */
            item_out := 
               SUBSTR (string_in 
                     , start_location_io 
                     , l_loc - start_location_io 
                      ); 
         END IF; 

         IF l_loc = 0 
         THEN 
            /* If the delimiter was not found, send back indication 
               that we are at the end of the list. */ 

            start_location_io := c_end_of_list; 
         ELSE 
            /* Move the starting point for the INSTR search forward. */ 
            start_location_io := l_loc + 1; 
         END IF; 
      END get_next_item; 
   BEGIN 
      IF string_in IS NULL OR delim_in IS NULL 
      THEN 
         /* Nothing to do except pass back the empty collection. */ 
         NULL; 
      ELSE 
         LOOP 
            get_next_item (string_in, l_startloc, l_item);
            IF LENGTH(l_item) != 0 THEN
                add_item (l_item);
            END IF; 
            EXIT WHEN l_startloc = c_end_of_list; 
         END LOOP; 
      END IF; 

      RETURN items_out; 
   END string_to_list; 

   FUNCTION string_to_list (string_in      IN VARCHAR2 
                          , outer_delim_in IN VARCHAR2 
                          , inner_delim_in IN VARCHAR2 
                           ) 
      RETURN nested_items_tt 
   IS 
      l_elements   items_tt; 
      l_return     nested_items_tt; 
   BEGIN 
      /* Separate out the different lists. */ 
      l_elements := string_to_list (string_in, outer_delim_in); 

      /* For each list, parse out the separate items 
         and add them to the end of the list of items 
         for that list. */    
      FOR indx IN 1 .. l_elements.COUNT 
      LOOP 
         l_return (l_return.COUNT + 1) := 
            string_to_list (l_elements (indx), inner_delim_in); 
      END LOOP; 

      RETURN l_return; 
   END string_to_list; 

   FUNCTION string_to_list (string_in      IN VARCHAR2 
                          , outer_delim_in IN VARCHAR2 
                          , mid_delim_in   IN VARCHAR2
                          , inner_delim_in IN VARCHAR2 
                           ) 
      RETURN second_nested_items_tt 
   IS 
      l_elements   items_tt; 
      l_return     second_nested_items_tt; 
   BEGIN 
      /* Separate out the different lists. */ 
      /* separated by group (claim) segments */
      l_elements := string_to_list (string_in, outer_delim_in); 

      /* For each list, parse out the separate items 
         and add them to the end of the list of items 
         for that list. */  

      FOR indx IN 1 .. l_elements.COUNT 
      LOOP 
         l_return (l_return.COUNT + 1) := 
            string_to_list (l_elements (indx), mid_delim_in, inner_delim_in); 
      END LOOP; 

      RETURN l_return; 
   END string_to_list;    
BEGIN
    loc_string := 
               group_seperator
            || -- seg 1
               segment_seperator
            || field_seperator
            || 'AB11'
            || field_seperator
            || 'AC1D'
            || field_seperator
            || 'AD2'
            || -- seg2
               segment_seperator
            || field_seperator
            || 'AE03'
            || field_seperator
            || 'AF6'
            || -- seg3
               segment_seperator
            || field_seperator
            || 'AG30'
            || field_seperator
            || 'AH00'
            || field_seperator
            || 'AIA'
            || field_seperator
            || 'DF1'
            || -- seg4
               segment_seperator
            || field_seperator
            || '5T0'
            || field_seperator
            || '772'
            || field_seperator
            || 'RE2'
            || field_seperator
            || 'IU1'
            || -- record 2
               group_seperator
            || segment_seperator
            || field_seperator
            || 'EW00'
            || field_seperator
            || 'JH1'
            || field_seperator
            || 'WQA'
            || -- seg2
               segment_seperator
            || field_seperator
            || 'RE02'
            || field_seperator
            || 'LL99'
            || field_seperator
            || 'IIKT';

        dataset := string_to_list (loc_string , group_seperator, segment_seperator, field_seperator);

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(   'List ' 
                              || ' contains ' 
                              || dataset.COUNT 
                              || ' elements'); 

      FOR outer_index IN 1 .. dataset.COUNT 
      LOOP 
--         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(   'List ' 
--                              || outer_index 
--                              || ' = ' 
--                              || dataset (outer_index) (1) (1) );

--         mid_items := string_to_list(dataset (outer_index), mid_delim_in);

         FOR mid_index IN 1 .. dataset(outer_index).COUNT -- mid_items.COUNT
         LOOP

            FOR inner_index IN 1 ..dataset(outer_index) (mid_index).COUNT
            LOOP

                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('INNER Value is ' || dataset(outer_index) (mid_index) (inner_index));


            END LOOP;

            fields := string_to_list(dataset(outer_index) (mid_index));

            idx := fields.FIRST;

--            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Segment: ' || get_description(idx, fields(idx)));
            WHILE idx IS NOT NULL
            LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( idx || ' = ' || fields(idx) );
                idx := fields.NEXT(idx);
            END LOOP;
         END LOOP;               
      END LOOP;  
END;
```

This example is indexed by PLS_INTEGER except the last loop that uses the VARCHAR2 indexed type.

So is there a way to change these all to VARCHAR2 based indexing and not have to worry about accessing an element that doesn't exist without using the EXISTS function?

My inital thought was I could have a record type for the segments I know like:

segment employee is:

```
 TYPE emp_rec IS RECORD(name VARCHAR2(30),
                        dob  DATE,
                        position VARCHAR2(30));
```

but if I come to that segment, how can I determine what values are missing or there for that matter, based on the record above?  I don't think this is possible since it is a PL defined record and I cannot gleam any metadata from it, at least to my knowledge.

Basically I am trying to figure out a way to make index by VARCHAR2 work instead of looping through via PLS_INTEGER